# Recordset in VBA for Excel does not return all records from table in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, vba, hana, recordset

This code is not bringing back the whole table. It always seems to be missing ~1-500 rows of data.

This is a big Data set around 75,000 rows so I question whether it has to do with the amount of data.

```vb
Sub GET_HANA_DATA2()

    driverHANA = "HDBODBC"

    Sheets("Deltas").UsedRange.ClearContents
    Sheets("Deltas").Range("AE1").Value = "Changed"

    ''''' HANA
    Set cn2 = New ADODB.Connection
    StrConn = "Driver={" & driverHANA & "};Servernode=<>; UID=<>; PWD=<>;"
    
    cn2.Open StrConn

    q = "SELECT * FROM <>." _
    & """<>"""
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cn2
        .Open q
        
        For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Sheets("Deltas").Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
        Next
        
        Sheets("Deltas").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        
        'MsgBox
    
        .Close
    End With
 
    
    'Colors columns
    Columns("AA:AC").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    'Filter Toggle
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then

        Sheets("Deltas").Range("A1:AE1").AutoFilter
     
    End If
End Sub
```

I use Data->Get Data->From Database->From SAP HANA Database. I put my query there and compare it to what the VBA code brings backs.

Looking through the data itself I am not finding anything distinct about the data that is not coming in the recordset.

Comment: From 75K records only between 1 and 500 are missing? That does **not** point to an issue with data volume, but rather to something that is "special" about those missing records. Have you tried to check the total record number in the recordset in the debugger?

Comment: No i have not. do you konw how i would do that? looking through the data itself i am not finding anything distinct about the data thats not coming in the recordset

Comment: Well, how do you find the missing records now? And using the VBA debugger is rather straight-forward - but not to explain it in a comment. Maybe just play around with it a bit...

Comment: i use
Data->Get Data->From Database->From SAP HANA Database
and i put my query in there and then compare it to what the vba code brings back